# How to convert my Array elements to numbers without deleting zero at the end

Tags: javascript

I want to convert my Array from this :

```
[ '0.500000', '0.333333', '0.166667' ]
```

to this :

```
[ 0.500000, 0.333333, 0.166667 ]
```

I tried `+`, `Number`, `parseInt`, `parseFloat` but none of them work.

Comment: You can't keep the trailing zeroes once it is converted to a number.

Comment: Numbers don't have trailing zeros. They don't have a format.

Comment: sounds to me like you're confused as to what you actually want. If you want formatted numbers to display in a UI, then what you already have is ideal - you want to keep them as strings. If you're interested in the underlying *number*, then 0.5 and 0.50000 are identical, which is why JS won't show you any difference.

Comment: There is no such thing as `0.500000` in Javascript. The internal representation will always be `0.5`.

Comment: If you want to make it clear to, say, a maintainer of your code that you are working to 6 decimal places you could use 500000e-6 etc, but it makes no difference to the system. Can you say a bit more about why you need the representation you have given?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments - you cannot retain the zero at the end unless it remains a string - if you convert the array values to numbers - you will lose all trailing zero's. If you need t o perform calculations - then you need to parse the strings into numbers when performing the calculation

but there is a workaround - if all the numbers have the same decimal places - you can use Math.pow() to multiply them by that power to get actual numbers.

This will convert your string array into a number array but with the numbers being mutiplied by  1 * (10 * the number of decimal places).

You can then use the values for performing calculations or whatever you need - just remember to divide by that 100000 to use them. Note that the toFixed() will convert the number to a string and provide the trailing zeros based on the number of decimal places you require.

**That said - this is a hacky workaround - I would simply convert them to numbers, perform my calculation and then pad the trailing zeros with toFixed(decimalPlaces). Simple is always best.**

```js
const arr = [ '0.500000', '0.333333', '0.166667' ];

const decimalPlaces = 6;

const numArr = arr.map(x => x * (1 * Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces)));



console.log(numArr);
  // gives [500000, 333333, 166667]

const stringArr = numArr.map(y => (y / (1 * Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces))).toFixed(decimalPlaces)) 

console.log(stringArr);
  // gives ["0.500000","0.333333","0.166667"]
```

Comment: I try to answer an algorithmic question and my answer is not accepted because my elements are strings.
This again gives me an array of string elements. What is the answer?

Comment: @ArezouSaremian What you're asking for is impossible. Either you misunderstood the question or it doesn't support JavaScript.

Comment: _I try to answer an algorithmic question and my answer is not accepted_ --> seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)